Cucumber I want to have a step that run a given step in try block
I have a automation project in cucumber and kotlin with a lot of steps,sometimes I want a step to be run and not stop the test if it fail aka running it inside try block(i calling this a soft step), I would like to make a tool that can take any given step given to him and run it inside a try block
the goals that i want to achieve:
less repeat in code.
no need to maintained with any new step added and exception when step change.
evrey step can be run normal or as soft step
I tried to find a way to run a step by the step name in code side, something like this:

When("click button")

fun clickButton() {

// click button

}



when("soft {string}")

fun softStep(step: String) {

 runCatching{

    When(step)

  }.onFailure {
    // document the failure
  }

}


feature file:
When soft "click button"

sadly the function When() don't run a step by given string
there is a function that do that?
if not how do i make one?
or there is different approach to achieve the same goals i want?
ideas I don't want to do:
-every step have a step that call his in function inside try (double the number of function)
-a function with when block to find the step (it would be a massive one that have to handel calling all step and change evrey time we add step or change step name)
feel free to ask me,
thanks for help.

If you want to modify/extend step logic w/o code duplication, and massive refactoring (adding try/catch everywhere), then I can recommend you looking at Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP).
I've resolved the same problem that you have successfully with the help of AspectJ, but it was a Java-based project.
I believe you should be able to do the same with a Kotlin-based project.
In a nutshell, AOP allows you to create a method execution 'interceptor' (step in your case), which will contain the try/catch block (with the step call inside) based on some condition, in case you need it to be optional (e.g. control the logic via some system property).
Then you can apply that method to all steps in the package(s) or class(es), or make it annotation-based (e.g. apply only to those steps that are annotated with some annotation).
